# Swapping `std::aligned_storage` instances containing non-trivially-copyable types - undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, swap, undefined-behavior, c++14

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/zgQz1P)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>   
using namespace std;

// Non-trivially-copyable type.
struct NTC
{
    int x;      
    NTC(int mX) : x(mX) { }    
    ~NTC() { cout << "boop." << x << endl; }
};

int main() 
{
    using AS = aligned_storage_t<sizeof(NTC), alignof(NTC)>;

    // Create two `std::aligned_storage` instances
    // and "fill" them with two "placement-new-constructed" 
    // `NTC` instances.
    AS as1, as2;        
    new (&as1) NTC{2};
    new (&as2) NTC{5};

    // Swap the `aligned_storages`, not their contents.
    std::swap(as1, as2);

    // Explicitly call `~NTC()` on the contents of the
    // aligned storage instances.
    NTC& in1{*static_cast<NTC*>(static_cast<void*>(&as1))};
    NTC& in2{*static_cast<NTC*>(static_cast<void*>(&as2))};     
    in1.~NTC();
    in2.~NTC();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Is the above code undefined behavior?**

Here's what I think that's happening:

- `NTC` is a non-trivially-copyable type.
- I'm creating two memory locations suitable to store `NTC` objects (`std::aligned_storage`).
- I construct two `NTC` instances directly into the memory locations.
- [`std::aligned_storage` instances are PODTypes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage).

  > This means the type is compatible with the types used in the C programming language, can be manipulated using C library functions: it can be created with std::malloc, it can be copied with std::memmove, etc, and can be exchanged with C libraries directly, in its binary form.
- Since the aligned storage instances are POD types, I should be allowed to move/swap/copy them around.
- Swapping the aligned storage instances means **take all the bytes from aligned storage A and swap them with all the bytes from aligned storage B**.
- Doing so will not call the destructor/copy-constructor of the internally stored `NTC` objects.

Are any of my points **incorrect**? If **undefined behavior** does occur, in what part of the program does it occur? And why?

---

New *potentially-correct/incorrect* information ([gathered from a deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29318269)):

- `std::aligned_storage` is pretty much just a typedef for a C-style array.
- [`std::swap` has an overload for C-style arrays since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).
- That overload [calls `std::swap_ranges`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges), which swaps every single element in the array.
- Therefore, swapping two `std::aligned_storage` instances should swap their contents, element by element.

**Am I making any mistake in these new assumptions?**

Comment: I initially mis-read and I could fix it right away but hvd got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly accessing the bytes of a buffer after a non-trivially-copyable type has been placed in it is a very bad idea, but not undefined just yet.

Attempting to access the buffer after swapping as a `NTC` violates the aliasing rules, [basic.lval]p10:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> (10.1) -- the dynamic type of the object,
>
> [....]

Copying a trivially copyable type through `memcpy` or equivalent is implied to preserve the dynamic type. No such implication is made for non-trivially copyable types, so after swapping, you no longer have any `NTC` objects to access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still have some doubts - what exactly is a **dynamic type**? Is it relevant **only with polymorphic objects** (which obviously are *non-trivially-copyable* as well)? If it is, would enforcing `T` types stored in `std::aligned_storage` instances to not be polymorphic (maybe through a `static_assert`) make swapping the aligned storage instances safe?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo For an lvalue, "dynamic type" is the type of the object to which the lvalue refers. It's defined in 1.3.7, and it's not only for polymorphic objects: given `struct A { }; struct B : A { } b; A &a = b;`, the dynamic type of `a` is `B`, but no language construct will make use of that dynamic type.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo For a somewhat practical example of how things could break with a non-trivially-copyable type, consider the pimpl idiom, but consider the case where the implementation type needs a back pointer for some reason. This cannot ever work if you swap the buffers like you do, even if the type has no virtual functions whatsoever.

Comment: So the UB occurs here `*static_cast<NTC*>(static_cast<void*>(&as1))`?  (where we have created a `NTC*` pointing at something that is not an `NTC`?)  Or at `in1.~NTC()` where we use it?  Amusingly, I think it might be the case if the OP had stored the pointer to `as1` as a `NTC*` returned by `new`, the call to `std::swap` would have been undefined behavior (as `swap` gets a reference to it as an aligned storage, and the unique-address aliasing requirement -- or maybe only if we got a pointer to it, hmm)

Comment: @Yakk Good question. The standard simultaneously says "A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function" ([dcl.ref]p5) and gives an example of how a reference can bind to an uninitialised `int` variable ([dcl.init.ref]p1). It's not clear to me whether the binding of the reference is valid. The destructor call definitely isn't, anyway.

Comment: @hvd an uninitialized `int` is a valid object in an uninitialized state.  `aligned_storage` is not a valid object of the type it fits, initialized or not, prior to construction (which can leave it uninitialized! (only for some types)).  Maybe?